# Error creating Controller using .NET cli codegenerator in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, command-line-interface

When I try to create controller using .NET cli codegenerator in my ASP.NET web mvc project:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project . controller  -name "Controllers\TempController"
```

getting this error:

[image]

(Controller name contains '\').

So where is my mistake?

Comment: Hello Did you try the solution provided? Did you have a chance to look at this [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0#controller-options)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have put the "Controllers"-part in the name-parameter since you want it in the Controllers-folder. Use -outDir-parameter for the folder:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project . controller  -name "TempController" -outDir "Controllers"
```

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0